# Почему отправка писем средствами PHP через сокеты выдает непонятные символы?

Tags: php, кодировка, сокет, email, sendmail

Пришло вот такое письмо в Thunderbird и Outlook:

> абаЛаИ бббаЛаКаА аНаЕ аОбаКббаВаАаЕббб, аПаОаПбаОаБбаЙбаЕ аОбаКбббб аЁа­а аВ аБбаАбаЗаЕбаЕ Google Chrome, аНаАаБбаАаВ аВ аАаДбаЕбаНаОаЙ бббаОаКаЕ аАаДбаЕб

Фото письма:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отправляется все через сокеты. В заголовки прописывается следующее:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset: UTF-8' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: " . (empty($from) ? MAILER_FROM_NAME." <".MAILER_FROM_EMAIL.">" : $from ). "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset: UTF-8' . "\r\n\r\n\r\n";

    $contentMail .= $headers;
    $contentMail .= $message . "\r\n";
```

В начале файла прописал: `header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");`. Файлы сами в UTF-8. `mb_detect_encoding` - показывает UTF-8. На экран и в консоль выводится все корректно.

В чем может быть проблема? Некоторые почтовые веб клиенты отображают нормально, но мне надо именно в тех программах.

Варианты с использованием PHP Mailer, перенастроить программы не годятся.

Comment: А вы смотрели дефолтные кодировки этих клиентов?

Comment: Смотрели, стоит либо UTF-8, либо WIN-1251. Причем в Outlook 2016 отображается нормально все. Есть ли способ как-то стандартизировать все, чтобы письмо у всех одинаково отображалось?

Comment: Попробуйте из заголовков убрать [кавычки](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/b3e10218-80bf-49da-958e-cd2a03f76944/10531077108710861073107710761080108410721103?forum=msoclientru)

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, нет кавычек вообще нигде

Comment: Покажите заголовки получившегося письма